# I only have one week's vacation

Tags: grammaire

In "Assimil New French with Ease", it says on page 230 that:

> J'ai seulement une semaine de vacances.

is the same as

> Je n'ai que deux semaines de vacances.

Instead, shouldn't it be

> Je n'ai que une semaine de vacances.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> J'ai **seulement** une semaine de vacances

With `seulement` in one word means "I only have one week of vacation".

> Je n'ai que deux semaines de vacances.

Means "I only have two weeks of vacation".

> Je n'ai **qu'une** semaine de vacances.

Means "I only have one week of vacation" so it is equivalent to the first sentence.

It seems that there is an error in "Assimil New French with Ease".

Comment: It may just be an ambiguity. As you say if you omit the 2 vs 1 difference, both forms convey the same meaning, with an emphasis on the "only" when using the first form, which I think you may convey better in English by saying "I have one week holidays only"